# EXCEL: Extracting Milliletres and Litres from cell using vba or formula

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to extract the Milliliters and Liters from text(Only the value, not the ml or Ltr), but as there is no specific standard, it is difficult to do a formula. Below is some examples of the types of descriptions I have:

```
- Settlement 2.5% (Settlement Discount)
- BAGDOL/1 (U-POL DOLPHIN GLAZE Brushable Stopper Bag 440ml)
- P38/5 (ISOPON P38 LIGHTWEIGHT FILLER 3Ltr)
- EGC21TT (EUROPEAN COATINGS PRIMER 4:1 HS 4Ltr TRIPLE TIGHT)
- RLT/1KIT (U-POL RAPTOR TINTABLE 750ml & 250ml STANDARD HARDENER KIT)
- CCWP/AL (U-POL CUSTOM CAN Pregassed Aerosol 400ml (Waterbased))
```

I have used the formula below which I feel I have over-complicated.:

```
=IF(LEN(IFERROR(MID(G2,FIND("ml",G2)-3,LEN(G2)),""))=0,IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(MID(G2,FIND("Ltr",G2)-2,LEN(G2)),"Ltr)","")*1000,""),IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(MID(G2,FIND("ml",G2)-3,LEN(G2)),"ml)",""),""))
```

So those with 440ml returns 440 and those that say 3Ltr return 3000 - But this is only if it is at the end of the cells text.

I want to be able to extract the value of the ml or Ltr no matter where it is in the text. Those that have more than one set of ml value in it, I want to sum them. Example `: 750ml & 250ml` should be 1000. `Settlement 2.5% (Settlement Discount)` should return 0.

Is there a simple way of doing this ? Id be happier with doing it in VBA, as I think this would be less complicated.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Probably best to use [tag:regex] looking for digits with set optional unit types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is probably a far better way of doing this using RegEx, but I'm not practiced in those dark arts so I'd use something like the following to get what you need:

```
Function getvolume(txt As String) As Long
    Dim wrd As Variant, wrds As Variant
    getvolume = 0
    If txt = "" Then Exit Function
    ' strip out characters that will confuse
    txt = Replace(txt, "(", " ")
    txt = Replace(txt, ")", " ")
    ' convert all to lower case
    txt = LCase(txt)
    ' split the text into individual "words"
    wrds = Split(txt, " ")
    For Each wrd In wrds
        If wrd Like "*ml" Then getvolume = getvolume + Val(Replace(wrd, "ml", ""))
        If wrd Like "*ltr" Then getvolume = getvolume + 1000 * Val(Replace(wrd, "ltr", ""))
    Next
End Function
```

So if your text is in `G2` then you'd use a formula of `=getvolume(G2)`

Comment: I've altered the declaration to make it suitable for `Option Explicit`.

Comment: You Sir, are brilliant!It worked like a bomb! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

[regex](/questions/tagged/regex) User Defined Function

```
Option Explicit

Function metricMeasure(str As String)
    Dim n As Long, unit As String, nums() As Variant
    Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object

    'with rgx as static, it only has to be created once; beneficial when filling a long column with this UDF
    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If
    metricMeasure = vbNullString

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "[0-9]{1,4}m?[lL]t?r?"
        If .Test(str) Then
            Set cmat = .Execute(str)
            'resize the nums array to accept the matches
            ReDim nums(cmat.Count - 1)
            'get measurement unit
            unit = Replace(cmat.Item(0), Val(cmat.Item(0)), vbNullString, 1, vbTextCompare)
            'populate the nums array with the matches
            For n = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
                nums(n) = Val(cmat.Item(n))
            Next n
            'convert the nums array to a subtotal with unit suffix
            metricMeasure = Application.Sum(nums) & unit
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

[image]